# Build APK stuck at Task :app:checkReleaseAarMetadata

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, apk, flutter-android

i am new in flutter.

When i run:

```
flutter apk build -v
```

it always stuck at

```
[+29946 ms] > Task :app:checkReleaseAarMetadata
```

I left it for almost an hour and nothing,
same happen when i run it on release or debug on my own device via usb debugging, but run perfectly on emulator on debug mode

any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I found the solution.

In the end tried to clean install Android Studio including sdk, gradle, etc by deleting android studio related stuff on %APPDATA%, %USERPROFILE%, %LOCALAPPDATA%.

After that i build the apk again from vscode console and it work.

I think the error occurred because of missing stuff in gradle or error during sdk installation.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> add the following line to android/build.gradle.try it and update is it fixed!
> ```

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        androidXCore = "1.7.0" // <-- Add this line
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    }
```

Comment: still same, stuck at Task :app:checkReleaseAarMetadata

Comment: include android/build.gradle and app/build.gradle files!

Comment: I tried reinstall android studio including delete .gradle and android studio related stuff and it works. I wouldn't think of redownload gradle if u didnt mention it. Thanks.